# Fetching data via Facebook connect taking over 10 seconds

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Our site uses Facebook connect. When a new user signs up we ask for permission to pull their interest data, their list of friends, and their friends' interests. Fetching this data used to be a very quick process (couple seconds). Over the last week or so, the time to fetch this data has increase to 10+ seconds.  According to Facebook insights, our site is not being throttled. We didn't make any changes to our site.

Anyone else experiencing this issue with Facebook? Have any ideas for how to address it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of 1/26 at 7:55 PM EST, the [live status page](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/) doesn't indicate any irregular activity.

Sometimes this occurs because a user simply has a lot of likes and interests. I would recommend making this operation asynchronous following a flow something like this:

- User connects with your app
- Get the access token and store it in a queue that a background process can access.
- Get all the information you need immediately to make the app work.

*Some time later*

- In a background process, grab an access token from the queue, parse it and handle it however you'd like.

A simpler, although less stable option, is redirecting the user to a page upon installation which makes an AJAX request to that page telling it to download the information from the graph. This keeps the response time low, but does require your user to have Javascript enabled and for them to stay on the destination page long enough for the request to be created.